# FPS in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

I am making game in cocos2d-iphone. What i noticed is some times my **FPS** decreases to **30.0** and than it becomes **60.0** which is **Normal FPS Rate**.

I want to know what is the reason of that. Because when it decreases to 30.0 , game become slow.

Is it because of **complex calculation and checking** which are performed for specific reason ? How not to decrease this FPS rate in game. Can any one guide me?

Comment: This can have any number of reasons. Inefficient code, inefficient rendering, the OS doing background processing. The fps drops because either the CPU or the rendering can't complete their update cycle within 16.7 milliseconds, and thus one frame is skipped, dropping the framerate to 30 fps.
There's a tool called Instruments that helps you narrow down such issues: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Too many calculations, too many drawn objects without batching are usually the main reason of low fps.

Comment: yes, In my update method is contentiously checking if box intersect other 60 odd boxes.And yes in my case its compulsory to check this.

Answer (score 0):

In my update method is contentiously checking if box intersect other 60 odd boxes. Thats the problem . One thing to make the app not clunky is to set the fps to a low 30.

Comment: By doing that, will it affect game smoothness? Actually i did that and game's FPS stays at 30 FPS.